# Send tweet to twitter via shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, twitter, command-line

I previously used a script to send a tweet to twitter, however has recently failed to work.

I am looking for a currently working simple shell to send a tweet to twitter. Any idea how I'd go about doing so?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84540/twitter-status-updates-from-command-line-via-curl

Comment: Or http://search.cpan.org/~getty/Text-Tweet-0.004/lib/Text/Tweet.pm

Comment: There's a free python library called "tweepy" and "python-twitter". You can use these to create a script, and they offer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are other scripts out there. Does this work for you?

http://supertweetnews.140plus.com/p/a-quick-example-of-bash-shell-scripts-for-posting-twitter-updates/ZeRfz

Comment: this is not working for me, does twitter have changeed anything?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of libraries out there that can do most of the work for you. Ballerina is a programming language that is pretty good at integration. You can use its built-in support for twitter to tweet from the shell. You can do something like this inside your script,

```
#!/bin/bash
MSG="WSO2 Ballerina goes well with shell.."
ballerina_utility_function()
{
        BALLERINA_SCRIPT_LOCATION="$BALLERINA_HOME/samples/twitterConnector/twitterConnector.bal"
        bash "$BALLERINA_HOME/bin/ballerina" "run" "main" "$BALLERINA_SCRIPT_LOCATION" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$MSG"
        return
}

RESPONSE="$(ballerina_utility_function $1 $2 $3 $4 $MSG)"
echo "-----> $RESPONSE"
```

then execute the script with the twitter API keys and tokens from the shell. Find the complete script and instructions here: http://ballerinagist.blogspot.com/2017/05/use-ballerina-to-extend-your-bash.html Look to http://ballerinalang.org/ for more information.